# Undefined symbols for architecture even though definitions exist?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

For some reason I keep getting the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
"___glewGetUniformLocation", referenced from:      
     changePerspective(unsigned int) in Viewing-ff0c66.o 

"___glewUniformMatrix4fv", referenced from:
      changePerspective(unsigned int) in Viewing-ff0c66.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Even though I have the correct library included:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp> 


glm::mat4 perspective(1.0f); 
glm::mat4 transform(1.0f); 
glm::mat4 camera(1.0f); 

void changePerspective(GLuint program) { 


    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "matrixThingy"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(perspective* camera* transform)); 
}
```

I have tried re-downloading the software and adding various linker options when executing, but I can't seem to get it to work. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Running this program on a Macbook Pro in Visual Studio Code

Comment: What is the command line you're using to compile this?

Comment: g++ -I/opt/local/include -g -o transMain Buffers.cpp Canvas.cpp ShaderSetup.cpp Shapes.cpp Viewing.cpp transMain.cpp -L/opt/local/lib -lglfw -framework OpenGL
-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo

Comment: Unless I'm missing it you're not linking with -lglew.

Comment: Thank you that was the issue!! Post it as the answer and I will mark it as the correct answer